# Clean way to stop Logstash

Tags: logstash

Let's imagine that I have a Logstash instance running, but would like to stop it cleanly, to change it's configs for example.

How can I stop the Logstash instance, while ensuring that it finish sending the bulks to Elasticsearch? I don't want to loose any logs while stopping logstash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Logstash 1.5 flushes the pipeline before shutting down in response to a SIGTERM signal, so there you should be able to shut it down with `service logstash stop`, the init.d script, or whatever it is that you usually use.

With Logstash 1.4.x a SIGTERM signal shuts down Logstash abruptly without allowing the pipeline to flush all in-flight messages, but you can send SIGINT to force a flush. However, some plugins (like the redis input plugin) don't handle this gracefully and hang indefinitely.

Comment: Great! Can you provide a link to some documentation that explains this behavior with more details?

Comment: I don't think it's documented (at least not for 1.4.x), but I can have a look. I figured it out by reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

With Logstash 2.3:

> Logstash keeps all events in main memory during processing. Logstash responds to a SIGTERM by attempting to halt inputs and waiting for pending events to finish processing before shutting down.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

`kill -TERM {logstash_pid}` also sends a `SIGTERM` signal, such as `service logstash stop`. [Logstash 7.15](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/shutdown.html)

`kill -SIGHUP {logstash_pid}` reload the config file and restart the pipeline.

If you run logstash using docker, the command `docker stop <logstash_container>` sends a `SIGTERM` signal. If you start the docker again variables like `:sql_last_value` returns to "1970-01-01"

`docker restart <logstash_container>` sends a `SIGHUP` so it is usefull to reload the pipeline keeping the provious values of variables such as `:sql_last_value`.